# How to set x:Reference Markup Extension programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to set the `x:Reference` Markup extension for a binding in code?

For example:

`{Binding SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference ComboList}}`

So i create a binding like this:

```
Binding b = new Binding("SelectedItem");
b.Source = //What to put here??
```

I was previously using `ElementName` but I had some issues with the NameScope as referred in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487649/binding-elementname-inside-a-datatemplate) because this binding is set in a ComboBox which is inside of a UserControl I created, and apparently if I use `ElementName` the namescope is limited only to that UserControl and not outside..

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you creating a binding in code to begin with? Post a screenshot of what you need.

Comment: Because I'm building a WPF Form designer where user drags and drops controls to a design surface and sets bindings through a property window. I use the binding info in the Properties Window to set those bindings programmatically.

Comment: `{x:Reference}` is a XAML construct, it's not available in C# code.

Comment: Then how can I refer to an `ElementName` outside of my UserControl boundaries if I'm creating the binding in code?

Comment: You can't. That doesn't make sense. If you need something inside the `UserControl` to have a property from the outside, you have to create that property as a `DependencyProperty` within the `UserControl` itself, then bind your element to that property via `RelativeSource`.

Comment: @HighCore is more right than not - while you can go down the route of trying to manually new up a `System.Windows.Markup.Reference` instance, force it to generate a value via `ProvideValue`, etc., it's a rats-nest you *don't* want to go down.

Comment: @HighCore, "then bind your element to that property via RelativeSource" How can I bind using `RelativeSource` if I still need to do a Name lookup to locate my source Control? RelativeSource only allows specifying Ancestor Types/Levels as far as I know

Comment: I mean, the DP should be in the `UserControl`, right? then you can `"{Binding MyProp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"`

Comment: Genius, that works!, if you enter an Answer for that I will mark it . Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comments into an answer:

> {x:Reference} is a XAML construct, it's not available in C# code

If you need something inside the `UserControl` to have a property from the outside, you have to create that property as a `DependencyProperty` within the `UserControl` itself, then bind your element to that property via `RelativeSource`:

In the UserControl code behind:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Some", typeof (SomeValue), typeof (YourUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(SomeValue)));

        public SomeValue Some
        {
            get { return (SomeValue) GetValue(SomeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SomeProperty, value); }
        }
```

Somewhere within the UserControl Visual Tree:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Some, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```