# How to bind a View directly to another View, in c# markup (no xaml, no ViewModel/codebehind)

Tags: data-binding, maui

This really seems like a simple thing but i cant figure it out.

Im not using xaml, pure c# markup to create views.
I have a `DataTemplate` and I can easily bind Views to and form a ViewModel code behind using c# markup. But now Id rather bind a `View` directly to another `View`.  The only examples i can find of this are in the xaml as is done in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PH9_bPu-ImQ)

So it seems as simple as this, which of course does not work as i suspect that `Label` `Binding` has no idea what the path to the `Border` is

```
internal class BinaryItemDataTemplate : DataTemplate
{
    internal BinaryItemDataTemplate()
    {
        LoadTemplate = static () =>
        {
            Label label = new() { Text = "unset" };
            var border = new Border();
            label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(border.IsFocused)); // whats the path/source

            return border;
        };
    }
}
```

As i stated I can simple do this and bind the `Border` to the ViewModel

```
border.SetBinding(Border.IsFocusedProperty, nameof(BinaryItem.IsFocused), BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

And bind that back to the `Label`

```
selectedLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(BinaryItem.IsFocused));
```

But Id like to do it directly as can be done with all that xaml nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you want to use `x:Reference` binding in code behind. However, [`x:Reference` is a XAML construct and it's not available in C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15530384/20118901).

As an alternative, you could customize your own bindings.

```
    LoadTemplate = static () =>
    {
        Label label = new() { Text = "unset" };
        var border = new Border();
        // use the following line to bind the label's Text property 
        // to the IsFocused Property of border
        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(source:border ,path:"IsFocused")); 

        return border;
    };
```

For more info, you could refer to [BindableObject.SetBinding(BindableProperty, BindingBase) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.bindableobject.setbinding?view=net-maui-7.0).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ya that was it thanks.  Documentation on no xaml UI design would help